# ruby on rails regexp or ends_with

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, yaml

I'm trying to prevent users from overdoing certain actions.

My problem is that I don't know what the best way is to check if the path of the action matches with what I define in the YAML file. As I see it could be either regex or something like `ends_with` method.

At the moment I have the following half ready code. I'm not sure if I should define the paths in the `YAML` the way I currently do and also not sure if I call a proper comparison in `rack_attack.rb`.

Could somebody help me out and explaining me why his/her recommended solution is the best here?

YAML:

```
logins_ip:
    limit: 5
    period: 30
    path: /users/sign_in

post_comment_creation: 
    limit: 5
    period: 45
    # Full route is /posts/:post_id/post_comments but post_id not required
    # since I wanna prevent users from commenting more than 5/45sec to all the
    # posts. Yet I may could use some regex that matches any number.
    path: /post_comments

messages_creation:
    limit: 10
    period: 10
    # Here I need this exact route since I wanna prevent users from
    # messaging more than 10/10sec in a given conversation
    path: conversations/:conversation_id/messages

default:
    period: 60
    limit: 10
    method: POST
```

rack_attack.rb

```
@config = YAML.load_file('config/rack_attack.yml').with_indifferent_access

    def from_config(key, field)
        @config[key][field] || @config[:default][field]
    end

    @config.keys.each do |key|
        Rack::Attack.throttle(key, limit: from_config(key, :limit), period: from_config(key, :period)) do |req|
        req.ip if /#{from_config(key, :path)}/.match(req.path.to_s) && from_config(key, :method) == req.env['REQUEST_METHOD']
    end
end
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what exactly the question is. Does your current code work? Or is there a problem with the code? Or are you asking "is there a better way to do this?" The different between `.end_with?` and a regexp is that the former will simply check if a string ends with some fixed string, while a regexp is, well, a regexp, and thus much more powerful. In general, you want to choose the simplest method.

Comment: Seems to be working now. Since I asked question I have changed to ends_with. I'm asking this because I'm not sure I'm doing the right way. Usually there is a preferred way to do something in rails.